# Python error:- TypeError: 'Timeout' object is not iterable while using simpy for AllOf

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, simpy

I was making a general simpy program but while making it the document said |,& are replaceable by  AnyOf, AllOf and the question also required us to use the statements rather than the symbols but when tried replacing the symbols with the statement the program started showing the following errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\kanu\Coding Languages\VS code\4th semester\Data simulation lab\lab 5\lab_5(statements).py", line 6, in test_condition
    ret = yield simpy.AnyOf(t1 , t2)
  File "C:\Users\kanu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\simpy\events.py", line 637, in __init__
    super().__init__(env, Condition.any_events, events)
  File "C:\Users\kanu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\simpy\events.py", line 520, in __init__
    self._events = tuple(events)
TypeError: 'Timeout' object is not iterable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\kanu\Coding Languages\VS code\4th semester\Data simulation lab\lab 5\lab_5(statements).py", line 22, in <module>
    env.run()
  File "C:\Users\kanu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\simpy\core.py", line 254, in run
    self.step()
  File "C:\Users\kanu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\simpy\core.py", line 206, in step
    raise exc
TypeError: 'Timeout' object is not iterable
```

these errors oucred in the following code: -

```
import simpy

def test_condition(env):
  t1, t2 = env.timeout(1, value='spam'), env.timeout(2, value='eggs')
  ret = yield simpy.AnyOf(t1 , t2)
  #assert ret == {t1: 'spam'}
  print(ret)

  t1, t2 = env.timeout(1, value='spam'), env.timeout(2, value='eggs')
  ret = yield t1 & t2
  #assert ret == {t1: 'spam', t2: 'eggs'}
  print(ret)

  
  e1, e2, e3 = [env.timeout(i) for i in range(3)]
  ret = yield simpy.AllOf( simpy.AnyOf ( e1,  e2),  e3)
  print(all(e.processed for e in [e1, e2, e3]))

env = simpy.Environment()
proc = env.process(test_condition(env))
env.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you havn't send `env` parameter to the function, using following code:

```
t1, t2 = env.timeout(1, value='spam'), env.timeout(2, value='eggs')
ret = yield simpy.AnyOf(env=env, events=[t1 , t2]) # pay attentions here!!!
```

what your code makes `AnyOf` function treat t1 as env and t2 as events and causing the error, for t2 is a Timeout instead of array.

Comment: to repeat, AnyOf takes two parameters, the env environment param, and a list of events. prof_fl built the list inline with the expression events=[t1, t2]

Comment: there is also a environment version with sytax env..any_of([list of events])